# Use variable as namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces, using

In some other file (`someusername\classes\MyClass` for instance), I have

```
<?php
namespace someusername;
class MyClass
{
  static function Test()
  {
    echo "working";
  }
}
?>
```

I have stumbled across an annoying little barrier:

```
<?php

$user = "someusername";
$class = "MyClass";

require_once "$user\\classes\\$class";

//This line should be the equivalent of 'use someusername as User;'
use $user as User; //Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' 

$c = "User\\$class";
$UserSpecificClass = new $c();
?>
```

I can get around it via the following, but the use statement would make things a lot nicer

```
<?php

$user = "someusername";
$class = "MyClass";

require_once "$user\\classes\\$class";

$c = "$user\\$class";

$UserSpecificClass = new $c();
?>
```

Is it possible to use variables in `use` statement in PHP? Or is it better to avoid the use statement with this approach?

Comment: What is the point of use if it's not to shorten or rename namespace+class and make the code clearer? Your code will never be clear and you can just keep the whole namespace+class in a variable anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing is performed at compile-time.

Assigning the variable is done at run-time after compilation, at which point any import should already be imported.

So this is not possible. Best solution would indeed be to use the FQN in a string and initialize that.

```
$c = "$user\\$class";

$UserSpecificClass = new $c();
```